# Can a DNS TXT record break a contact form?

Tags: domain-name-system, txt-record

This may be an odd question but I'm looking for a definitive answer once and for all.

I've been doing some research on TXT records and how they work, but I haven't been able to find out for sure. Everything I've read suggests that the presence of a TXT record would never interfere with the mail delivery of a contact form, but can anyone confirm this for me?

Is there any type of TXT record that would prevent a contact form from working? Or any situation in which the presence of a TXT record would prevent a contact form from working?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Thanks for the replies! I'll add some context, since it is a fairly vague question. A TXT record was added to the domain to verify ownership. It has DZC as the host and random characters as the value. The site developer is now saying that that TXT record is breaking the contact form. To my knowledge, a TXT record like that wouldn't interfere with anything as it's sole purpose is to verify ownership. I'm now trying to find out for certain whether or not it's possible that what he's saying is true.

It seems much more likely that the contact form issue is caused by something else, but I'd like to rule this out for sure. However I understand if maybe it's not possible to do that with certainty.

Comment: There’s so much that could go wrong when a contact form tries to communicate with a mail server that a bad TXT record would be pretty far down my list of possible troubleshooting points.

Comment: The answer to "Is there any way that <X> could prevent <Y> from working?" is almost certainly "Yes", no matter what X and Y are. To assert otherwise is very difficult -- much like proving a negative. If you could provide some context as to what it is about a TXT record that you think is breaking a contact form, or some examples, we'll be more able to help.

Comment: @DougDeden You're right, context might help. I've edited the question to include some context.

Comment: The scenario you’re describing seems unlikely unless the code behind that contact form is looking for that specific TXT record and expecting a different value. Could you have the developer describe in more detail why they believe in this specific cause of the problem? Also, are they the developer of the entire web service including the contact form - in which case they can be expected to know what it does that could be interfered with by the DNS record - or is the form a third-party plugin of some sort?

Comment: Agreed, your developer needs to provide a much more detailed explanation. What has been posted here so far doesn't do anything to explain the problem or point to a solution.

Comment: I agree, I think it might just be an excuse for why the form isn't working. He's also using as a reason to up-sell into a new email plan entirely. I'm going to be asking for more explanation but I wanted to be a little more educated before I did.

Answer (score 5):

If TXT record contains an [SPF record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) then it definitely can break mail delivery.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is possible. A TXT record is just text stored in the DNS, a human or a machine can read it and process it.

So, if you want, you can create a contact form or a script that will perform this check and look for a specific TXT value before doing something.